# mongodb map reduce without saving new results

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a very simple mongodb map reduce situation.  I need something similar in mysql world to:

```
select distinct(cookie) from table;
```

I found map reduce is my tool for this in mongo.  So I wrote this:

```
map2 = Code("function () { emit(this.cookie, 1);}")
reduce2 = Code("function (key, values) {return 1;}")
totalunique = collection.map_reduce(map2, reduce2, out={"reduce":aggregatedcollection}, query=query).count();
```

Very simple so far.  I can run this via cron and that keeps `aggregatedcollection` pretty well up to date.  I save a timestamp variable to put in my query to make sure I handle every row only once.

Here's my question.  Let's say at timestamp `t1` I have `c1` values in that collection.  Shortly after that, I run it again at timestamp `t2` and it returns `c2` values.  But on this subsequent running at `t2`, I want it to return `c2`, **but I don't want the new values in `c2` to be saved in `aggregatedcollection`.**

Or to put it another way, I want to run it the second time at `t2`, have it return `c2`, **but have `aggregatedcollection` only be filled with `c1` (the values from the first run).**

So after running at `t2`, I want it to return `c2` and have `c1` in `aggregatedcollection`, those are the only parameters of this problem.

It seems I should focus on the [out option](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions) of the map reduce function, but none of those options seem to be what I want.

Of course, I could copy the collection to a temp collection, do the work on that, then drop it, but that would take far too much time.

Comment: Why not just call `collection.distinct('cookie')`?

Comment: How many distinct values do you have to count?  Will these fit within the [16MB document limit](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents#Documents-MaximumDocumentSize) for inline results?

Comment: Sorry, there are about 7 million records.  The distinct() function works, but it takes a really long time, and map_reduce is very fast if you keep the cached collection up to date.  I should have included this information to begin with.

Comment: If `distinct()` works you should also be able to do an [inline Map/Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions) .. but it sounds like you want to use `c1` as a MapReduce cache when running `c2` (without modifying `c1`)?

Comment: Yes, `c1` represents a lot of work, and it took a lot of time to create (running it via cron for weeks/months).  'Starting' with `c1` to get to my ultimate goal of `c2` is very important as it saves a tremendous amount of time.

Comment: I don't think there is any straightforward way to achieve what you are after; MapReduce only takes a single collection as input but I believe you want to have two (the original `c0` and the `c1` "cache")?  You could run an inline MapReduce or Aggregation Framework query on both collections and combine the result, but that only gains you some efficiency if the `c1` collection isn't already a subset of `c0`.  How does your `distinct()` query work for this scenario?

Comment: distinct takes over a minute, this map reduce takes less than a second

Comment: So can you use MapReduce with inline output?  If distinct() works, the inline M/R should as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Below this will result the output in Screen..

```
var options = {out: { "inline": 1 }, query : query};  
db.colls.mapReduce(_mapper, _reducer, options);
```